# Save tensor as JPEG image with tf.map_fn - Python/TensorFlow

Tags: python, python-2.7, image-processing, tensorflow, tensor

I have a function that returns me a variable called **layer** - images in the format:

```
<tf.Tensor 'Conv2D_1:0' shape=(?, 16, 16, 1) dtype=float32>
```

I need to save these images in .jpeg.

So far I've thought of doing this:

```
# Reshape into tf.image.encode_jpeg format
images = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(layer, tf.uint8)

train_batch_size = 300
```

And in session = tf.Session ()

```
images_encode = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.encode_jpeg(x), images, dtype=tf.uint8) # There was no error in this line, is it right?
```

**My doubt now is how to configure it to save them?**

I've tried this:

```
# That means it will only scroll through my 300 images
# And it's these 300 images that I want to save
x_batch, y_true_batch = next_batch_size(train_batch_size)

feed_dict_train = {x: x_batch, y_true: y_true_batch}

result = session.run(images_encode, feed_dict=feed_dict_train)

format_str = ('%s.jpeg')
fr = format_str % datetime.now()
f = open(fr, "wb+")
f.write(result.eval())
f.close()
```

But I'm getting the following error:

```
InvalidArgumentError (see above for traceback): TensorArray dtype is uint8 but Op is trying to write dtype string.
    [[Node: map_5/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3 = TensorArrayWriteV3[T=DT_STRING, _class=["loc:@map_5/TensorArray_1"], _device="/job:localhost/replica:0/task:0/cpu:0"](map_5/while/TensorArrayWrite/TensorArrayWriteV3/Enter, map_5/while/Identity, map_5/while/EncodeJpeg, map_5/while/Identity_1)]]
```

My placeholders are:

```
# Placeholder variable for the input images
x = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, img_size_flat], name='x')

# Reshape 'x'
x_image = tf.reshape(x, [-1, img_size, img_size, num_channels])

# Placeholder variable for the true labels associated with the images
y_true = tf.placeholder(tf.float32, shape=[None, num_classes], name='y_true')
```

Comment: Please let me know if you still need help or if the answer solves your problem.

Comment: @Patwie, I'm sorry for the delay, I've been busy these days!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your are almost done. The type needs to be a `tf.string`:
This gives a noisy image:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import numpy as np

noise = np.random.randn(3, 128, 128, 1).astype(np.float32) * 255
# your data
layer = tf.convert_to_tensor(noise)

images = tf.image.convert_image_dtype(layer, tf.uint8)
images_encode = tf.map_fn(lambda x: tf.image.encode_jpeg(x),
                          images, dtype=tf.string)


def write_jpg(buf, fn):
    with open(fn, 'wb') as f:
        f.write(encoded_jpegs[0])

with tf.Session() as sess:
    encoded_jpegs = sess.run(images_encode)

    for k, jpg in enumerate(encoded_jpegs):
        with open("test%03i.jpg" % k, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(jpg)
```

Comment: This was very helpful. But it still is not what I need, I need to save each of the 300 images individually, for example: `test1.jpg, test2.jpg, ..., test300.jpg`. And I need them in their original form with no noise. For the idea is to later generate the histograms of these images.

Comment: You can always concat these images or use tf.py_func

Comment: I added the loop to write all images and they are **without** noise. I just used noise as an example. The `layer` can be any image!

Comment: I'm getting the following error: `InvalidArgumentError: You must feed the value for placeholder 'x' tensor with dtype float`

Comment: Then use `sess.run(images_encode, {x: numpy_array})`